# How can I covert each string of an array to be an Object in the array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, object

I am having this array.

```
const array = ["Pizza","Pasta","Choco"];
```

I want to do this:

```
const array = [["Pizza"],["Pasta"],["Choco"]];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each element to an array

Comment: @NickParsons can u write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can provide a function (`str => [str]`) which wraps each of your string food elements in an array. This will give you a new array, which contains all your elements nested within their own arrays.

See example below:

```js
const array = ["Pizza","Pasta","Choco"];
const result = array.map(str => [str]);
console.log(result);
```